# Laravel 8 route clears errors set in controller, while direct access to view is ok

Tags: routes, error-handling, laravel-8

In a controller LoginController.authenticate, if I try to redirect to previous page with this code:

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
  'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
]);
```

The correct view is displayed but error message is not shown.

If I change the code to this:

```
return view('auth.login')->withErrors([
   'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
]);
```

the view is displayed  with the error message.

My route definition is :

```
Route::middleware(['guest'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])
        ->name('login');

    Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate'])
        ->name('login');
});
```

Artisan route:list confirms login routes are using web middleware:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                 | Name  | Action                                                     | Middleware                                  |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | login               | login | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@showLoginForm         | web                                         |
|        |          |                     |       |                                                            | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated |
|        | POST     | login               | login | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@authenticate          | web                                         |
|        |          |                     |       |                                                            | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

I don't understand why routing makes errors disappear.

I tried to disable all middleware but this did not change anything.

with routing used, var_dump($errors) in view gives:

```
 class Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag#326 (1) { protected $bags => array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 0):

\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class was in $middlewareGroups/web, moving it to $routeMiddleware solves the issue!

Comment: format your answer in better way